# How to remove categories for Business Gmail completely

Tags: gmail

Gmail has built-in categories like Social, Promotions, Updates and Forums. As a system developer I get a lot of mails from automated system notifications and these seem to get categorized by Gmail as either Updates or Forums. This is super annoying and I'd really like Gmail to stop doing this. I can't seem to find a setting anywhere that stops the built-in categories from being applied. I already of filters in place to move some of these notification mails to the relevant labels I want, but they still get categorized as Forums or Updates.

Any ideas on how to stop this?

I'm using Gmail via a web browser, no fancy mail clients.

UPDATE
I forgot to mention this a company mailbox so not sure if we have all the options as a normal user. For one, I see no categories option under settings:

[image: My inbox settings]

Comment: The answer below by freginold, although not applicable to me, is not in the duplicate question from 2014 so perhaps things have changed since then? Also, this relates to business mail so it may be different to?

Comment: You don't have the + sign mentioned in the accepted answer of the duplicate question?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn those categories off in Settings:

- Click the **Settings** button (gear icon) in the upper right of your inbox
- Select **Settings**
- Click the **Inbox** heading
- Uncheck any categories you don't want Gmail to use

[image]

- Click the **Save Changes** button at the bottom of the screen

If you disable a category, any emails currently in that category will be moved to your inbox.

Note: this list only appears if you have **Inbox type** set to "Default."

Comment: Thanks but I don't see that option. See updated question please.

Comment: If you click the gear (Settings) icon, do you have the "Configure Inbox" option? You can deselect the categories from there as well.